# Date value set in the form field outside the modal form

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui

I have printed the same form twice on the same page. One inside a modal, the other outside. When I click on a date from the datepicker of the modal form, the date value is set in the form field outside the modal form. I don't really understand why this is happening. I would be very grateful if anyone can give me a way to solve this.

**Form:**

```
<form class="col s12 api-save-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="connection_date" class="datepicker dateinput form-control hasDatepicker" id="id_connection_date"> 
    <input type="text" name="disconnection_date" class="datepicker dateinput form-control hasDatepicker" id="id_disconnection_date"> 
    <input type="text" name="re_connection_date" class="datepicker dateinput form-control hasDatepicker" id="id_re_connection_date"> 
</form>
```

**Form inside modal:**

```
<div class="modal">
    <form class="col s12 api-save-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="connection_date" class="datepicker dateinput form-control hasDatepicker" id="id_connection_date"> 
        <input type="text" name="disconnection_date" class="datepicker dateinput form-control hasDatepicker" id="id_disconnection_date"> 
        <input type="text" name="re_connection_date" class="datepicker dateinput form-control hasDatepicker" id="id_re_connection_date"> 
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: In HTML, IDs must be unique. Having duplicate IDs will cause scripting issues. Please also provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example